Proving $pa^2+qb^2+rc^2\ge 4\sqrt{pq+qr+rp} \cdot S_{\Delta ABC}$
I want to prove the inequality:
$$pa^2+qb^2+rc^2\ge 4\sqrt{pq+qr+rp} \cdot S_{\Delta ABC}$$
$a,b,c$ are the three sides of $\Delta ABC$, $ p,q,r\in R^+$ .
I think this is a variant of Weisenböck's inequality:
$$a^2+b^2+c^2≥4√3S_{\Delta ABC}$$
Thanks for help.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The inequality you want to prove is equivalent to
$$(a^2+b^2-c^2+a^2+c^2-b^2)p+(a^2+b^2-c^2+b^2+c^2-a^2)q+(a^2+c^2-b^2+b^2+c^2-a^2)r\geq2\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}(a^2+b^2-c^2)(a^2+c^2-b^2)\sum_{cyc}pq}$$
which is true by C-S.

Can you prove it in detail? I still can't understand. Thank you very much！

@Lichium just sit down with a pen and paper and break down the inequality you are after. It is exactly the same as the one I have given.
